# How to Insert 11M record from dataframe using morgrify psycopg2 best approach in PostgreSQL DB optimized method

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, optimization

I am having  ct_data dataframe with two columns imjp_number(20 digit varchar) and imct_id(text)as 11M record , for 1M, 3M it insert all record in 63sec and 210sec successfully, My concern is with 11M record at one Go.

```
# Creating a list of tupples from the dataframe values
tpls = [tuple(x) for x in ct_data.to_numpy()]

args_str = b','.join(cursor.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x) for x in tpls)

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dummy_data_table VALUES " + args_str.decode('utf-8'))

conn.commit()

cursor.close()
```

when I try to insert 11M record to dummy_data_table  using above method it throughs below error

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO dummy_data_table  VALUES " + args_str.decode('utf-8'))
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

I am thinking  to split and divide my ct_data dataframe into 3M each then try to insert that will be require manual change in script like file key as I am reading csv file from s3 bucket, or else how can I insert all 11M records at one go in my PostgreSQL db table.

Last option comes in my mind is use chunk size for ct_data dataframe to insert how can I achieve this best possible way. Please suggest me option and way to do it .

Comment: you should use `cursor.execute_many` i think  ... you should really never ever ever do `cursor.execute("SOME_STRING"+something)` ... use the variable binding functions that it offers

Comment: Let me try and check...@JoranBeasley